# Wrong Encoding while write file (russian lang)

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding

Asp.Net Core 3.1 Web Api:

I try to write text strings (russian lang) into FileStream and then send it into browser.

Like this:

```
var fStream = new FileStream(Path.GetTempFileName(), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, 1048, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
```

Get bytes:

```
 byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"русский текст");
                fStream.Write(array);
  fStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return fStream;
```

And then send it into browser:

```
 return File(fileStream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
```

But i see not valid symbols like: ÐšÐ¾Ð¼Ð¿Ð¾Ð½ÐµÐ½Ñ

What i do wrong? I use UTF8, maybe it is not good choice?

Comment: did you tried add charset to content type ? like `text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Comment: it works! thsnk you!

Comment: The browser header has a language and the language has to be set correctly so the right fonts are used.

Comment: Why do you create a file to write your stuff into it and then let read it again? This a huge performance bottleneck as I/O is expensive. Why don’t you directly return your text? Just doing `return "text"` will automatically create a text/plain UTF-8 response.